# Let $R=\mathbb{Z}/2[x]$ and $I=R(x^{17}-1)$. Is there a nonzero element $y$ of $R/I$ with $y^2=0$?

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification

> Let $R=\mathbb{Z}/2[x]$ and the ideal $I=R(x^{17}-1)$. Is there a non zero element $y$ of $R/I$ with $y^2=0$?

My approach: Suppose there is $y=\bar{f}(x)$ with $f(x)\in R$, then $\bar{f}(x)\not\in R(x^{17}-1)$ and $f(x)^2=(x^{17}-1)g(x)$. We have that $(x-1)|(x^{17}-1)g(x)$ and the 17th-cyclotomic polynomial also divides $(x^{17}-1)g(x)$ hence they divide $f(x)^2$ and since they are irreducible they both divide $f(x)$. So $(x^{17}-1)|f(x)$ which is a contradiction.

Is this correct or have I missed something?

Comment: Do you know for sure that the 17th cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible in $R$? If so, you'd need to provide proof of that (we know it's true for $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$, but this might not be the case for your $R$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, modulo the proof that the 17-th cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible. (note: it appears not to be!)

A slightly easier approach would be to show that $x^{17}-1$ has no repeated factors, by comparison with its derivative.

Comment: Any hints on how to show that the 17-th cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible in $R$?

Comment: @user150391 On closer examination, I don't think this polynomial _is_ irreducible, since $2$ is not a primitive root modulo $17$.  But, again, it is enough just to show that it has no repeated factors.

Comment: After showing that $x^{17}-1$ has no repeated roots how does the argument continues? Isn't possible that $g(x)$ has a common root with $x^{17}-1$ ?

Comment: @user150391 $g(x)$ isn't important.  Just follow the same proof you already used—you were using the factors $X-1$ and $\Phi_{17}$, but the proof works with an arbitrary list of non-repeated factors.

Comment: Sorry I cannot follow the argument.

Comment: @user150391  You wrote the argument.  If $r_i$ is an irreducible factor, then it is a factor of $p^2$, so it is a factor of $p$...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like 17th-cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible, so your approach falls down. Here's another go.

For $[y]^2=0$ ($[y]$ is $y \; mod \; I$), we must to have $y^2 \in R(x^{17} - 1)$.
If $(x^{17} - 1)$ has a repeated root, we can factor it as $x^{17} - 1 = g^2\prod f_i$. Then, $y = g^\prod f_i$ will have square $y^2 = g^2\prod f_i^2 = (x^{17} - 1)\prod f_i$, which leads to $y^2=0$.

We must hence show that $x^{17} - 1$ has no repeated roots. We can see this by taking the derivative : an equation has a repeated root if its derivative also has that root. The derivative of $x^{17} - 1$ is $17x^{16}$, whose only roots are $0$. Many, many zeroes. Zero, however, is clearly not a root of $x^{17} - 1$. Hence there are no shared roots and the problem is solved.